# Error 1064 declaring variable inside trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble declaring a variable inside a trigger.

```
SET DELIMITER ;;
BEGIN
DECLARE qtyNow INT;
SET qtyNow = (
    SELECT qty
    FROM warehouse
    WHERE bin_id = 'GA66'
);
DECLARE need INT;
SET need = (
    SELECT min_level
    FROM warehouse
    WHERE bin_id = 'GA66'
);
END;;
SET DELIMITER ;
```

I get error `#1064` which means illegal syntax. I don't see where I went wrong. I even removed all that bulk and just had

```
DECLARE qtyNow INT;
```

And this single line still pops the error.

Comment: I'm supposing you didn't [read the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems.

One, you have a BEGIN...END block but you are not declaring a trigger.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html says:

> BEGIN ... END syntax is used for writing compound statements, which can appear within stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events).

You can't use BEGIN...END as a bare statement. It must be part of a CREATE TRIGGER, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE FUNCTION, or CREATE EVENT.

Two, you have two DECLARE statements in your block, with a SET in between.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html says:

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

You are trying to use a second DECLARE after you have done another statement, SET. Do all your DECLAREs up front.

Comment: Thank you. I only posted a snippet from my trigger. Declaring everything upfront made it work, thanks!

Comment: @gator, in the future, please make it clear that you are posting an excerpt of your code.